# Error generation due to settings.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

-Created a project in django with 'CustomUser' model derived from 'AbstractUser' in an app 'users'
-Below is the settings file snippet.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',


    'crispy_forms',
    'users',
```

I get following error while running python manage.py makemigrations command with unsuccessful migration.

```
ValueError: The field authtoken.Token.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

After much trial and error, I have removed  'rest_framework.authtoken' from the Installed app and the migration error disappeared and my site become functional. Problem is I want to user rest_framework and token based authorisation but if I keep 'rest_framework.authtoken' in settings, migration is not taking place.

Please help

Comment: Can you provide the model file where you define `user`? The error doesn't look like its saying there's anything wrong with the authToken, but rather the lack of a user model. Post the user model as well so we can validate it for correct syntax. Let's try to fix this!

Comment: What is your custom model name?

Comment: CustomUser is the name of custom user model derived from Abstractuser model. This model is in users app.

Comment: ~~~
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    # add additional fields in here

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
~~~